# ClassNotFoundException running Flyway Migrate task with java callback

Tags: maven, flyway

I am trying to implement a FlyWay java callback. However, flyway doesn't seem to find my class.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:6.0.0-beta:migrate (default-cli) on project odin_build: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to instantiate class ch.x.dp.test1 : ch.x.dp.test1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:6.0.0-beta:migrate (default-cli) on project odin_build: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to instantiate class ch.x.dp.test1 : ch.x.dp.test1
/snip.../
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.x.dp.test1
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
```

It seems that Flyway cannot find the class.

Here my java class:

```
package ch.x.dp;

import org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.Callback;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.Context;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.Event;

public class test1 implements Callback {

    public test1() {
        System.out.println("sldhksjhdkghd");
    }

    public boolean supports(Event event, Context context) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean canHandleInTransaction(Event event, Context context) {
        return false;
    }

    public void handle(Event event, Context context) {
    }
}
```

My pom contains the following:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
```

and

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${flyway.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <locations>classpath:ch.x.dp,filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration</locations>
                    <callbacks>
                        <callback>ch.x.dp.test1</callback>
                    </callbacks>
<snip/>
            </plugin>
```

I have verified that my mvn package calls create a jar in /target that contains my test1 class.

What else could be missing? How can I tell that FlyWay is actually using that jar?

Comment: Are you able to run `flyway -X migrate` from the command line? That will give you debug information including all the paths that Flyway is using to gather up migrations and callbacks.